# Confused about conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Could someone tell me if my logic for the following probability question is correct?

A scientific experiment has been under taken to evaluate the feeding habits of a new species of parrot in a forest bird population. The probabilities for each nut is independent.

```
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Nut Type             | # Nuts Eaten by Parrot  | # Nuts Eaten by Other Birds Species |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Peanuts              | 46                      | 20                                  |
| Walnuts              | 25                      | 80                                  |
| Pecan                | 63                      | 52                                  |
| Almonds              | 10                      | 75                                  |
| Total Nuts Evaluated | 350                     | 550                                 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

I am asked to evaluate $P(Almonds|!Parrot)$ and $P(Peanuts|Pecan)$.

I am confused, would $P(Almonds|!Parrot) = 75/550 = 0.136$ in this case? Or is $0.136$ just $P(!Parrot \wedge Almond)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $P(\text{almond | not parrot})$.

$P(\text{almond and not parrot})=\frac{75}{350+550}$, that is the denominator have to consider both types of birds.

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate on the second part more? I don't fully understand the denominator part.

Comment: @DaynaB It is: $P(\text{almond and not parrot})=\dfrac{n(\text{almond and not parrot})}{n(\text{parrot})+n(\text{not parrot})}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks!